# Share Plotly dash project

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am a beginner in data science and I don't understand how to share my project with my friends
I try to

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
])

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)  # Turn off reloader if inside Jupyter
```

[image]

but it started my dash project in localhost, so, I would like to know how I can share my project with friends (to do a clickable clink, not in localhost)

Comment: `app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", ...)` and users in local network could access it using your `IP` (something like `192.168.1.1`). But problem can be with access from internet because there are routes (hardware) between your computers and intenet and they may block redirections on some port (all for your security - to block hackers) and you can't change it . Usually port 80 can be open. Eventually you may try special programs to redirect your ports - like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) - but free version gives random address which changes when you restart program

Comment: You would need to host your app somewhere and expose it to the web. You could look into a service such as AWS, Google Cloud, or Azure, or set up a machine yourself. You would need a web address as well. It would be quite a bit of work if you've never done that before. If your friends know how to run Python code, then you could just send them your project/notebook and have them run it locally.

Comment: If you have your code in a Jupyter notebook, you could create an account on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/), which would convert the notebook to an HTML webpage that people can view.